# how to load json file to external event object to full calendar events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

html file in that i can able to parse the json file by using $ajax method  but when i try to build external events from this .json file its not displaying the events on the calendar and even i am not getting any error please help me out.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: h,
    defaultView: 'month',
    slotMinutes: 15,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true,
    drop: function (date, allDay) {
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        copiedEventObject.className = $(this).attr("data-class");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    },
    events: [function () {
        for (i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
            {
                title: (even[i].title);
                start: (even[i].start);
                backgroundColor: (even[i].backgroundColor);
                allDay: (even[i].allDay);
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

i can able to insert few static events to the code this works but i am not getting the code for dynamic events

```
events: [
                    {
                        title: 'test 1',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('red'),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'test 2',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                        backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('red'),
                        allDay: false
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'test 3',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('red'),
                        allDay: false
                    }
]
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> My json file is </h1>
[
    {
        "title": "Event",
        "start": "new Date(y, m, 28)",
        "backgroundColor": "Metronic.getBrandColor('yellow')",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "title": " Event for the day ",
        "start": "new Date(y, m, 15)",
        "backgroundColor": "Metronic.getBrandColor('yellow')",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "title": "event for android",
        "start": "new Date(y, m, 20)",
        "backgroundColor": "Metronic.getBrandColor('red')",
        "allDay": false
    }
]
```

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle

Comment: There is a typo in your for loop: even.length